# How to Modify a Running Gazebo Simulation?

Tags: gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

So I am using roslaunch command to simulate a simple Gazebo world file which contains some cubic obstacles. I have a question which I have not been able find any solution for:
Once the simulation is up and running, can I add any objects to Gazebo simulation without having to use the graphical user interface? I am using ROS Hydro and Gazebo-1.9.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Cheers,

Ali

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6260/how-to-modify-a-running-gazebo-simulation?/) by [ali_mohandes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/674/ali_mohandes/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-05-21**:
Could you please update the answer and include which version of gazebo are you using?

**Comment by [ali_mohandes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/674/ali_mohandes/) on 2014-05-21**:
Sure, it is ROS Hydro and Gazebo -1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are at least two ways of doing this:

1. From the command line: using the gzfactory tool (look at the spawn parameter). The [user guide](http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/started__commandlinetools.html) described it perfectly.
2. Programmatically: using a world plugin as described in the [corresponding tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=plugins_world)

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ali_mohandes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/674/ali_mohandes/) on 2014-05-21**:
Thanks a lot. I used gzfactory and it worked.
I appreciate your help.